# Some author name not displayed fully

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am completely new to LaTex... I have created a bibtex file, but unfortunately , among tha author names, some of them are being displayed fully and the rest are being abbreviated , like the name "Tom van der Poll" is getting displayed as "T. v. d. P". It is happening for some names while not for other names... Please help
The paper is "Host–Pathogen Interaction in Invasive Salmonellosis"
by "Hanna k. de Jong, Chris M. Parry, Tom van der Poll, W. joost Wiersinga"

```
@article{ 1,
        AUTHOR={Anu Raghunathan and Jennifer Reed},
        TITLE={Constraint-based analysis of metabolic capacity of Salmonella typhimurium during host-pathogen interaction},
        JOURNAL={BMC Systems Biology},
        YEAR={2009},
},

@article{ 2,
        AUTHOR={Hanna k. de Jong and Chris M. Parry and Tom van der Poll and W. Joost Wiersinga},
        TITLE={Host–Pathogen Interaction in Invasive Salmonellosis},
        JOURNAL={PLOS Pathogens},
        YEAR={2012},
 },

@article{ 3,
        AUTHOR={Vinod Scaria and Manoj Hariharan and Beena Pillai and Souvik Maiti and Samir k Brahmachari},
        TITLE={Host–virus genome interactions: macro roles for microRNAs},
        JOURNAL={Cellular Microbiology},
        YEAR={2007},
 },

@article{ 4 ,
        AUTHOR={Zhumur Ghosh and Bibekanand Mallick and Jayprokas Chakrabarti },
        TITLE={Cellular versus viral microRNAs in host–virus interaction},
        JOURNAL={Nucleic Acids Research},
        YEAR={2009},
},

@article{ 5 ,
        AUTHOR={Vinod Scaria and Manoj Hariharan and Samir K Brahmachari},
        TITLE={Host-virus interaction: a new role for microRNAs},
        JOURNAL={BioMedCentral},
        YEAR={2006},
 },

@article{ 6 ,
        AUTHOR={Renate Konig and Yingyao Zhou},
        TITLE={Global Analysis of Host-Pathogen Interactions that Regulate Early-Stage HIV-1 Replication},
        JOURNAL={Cell},
        YEAR={2008},
},

@article{ 7,
        AUTHOR={Man Lung Yeung and Laurent Houzet and Venkat S.R.K. Yedavalli and and Kuan-Teh Jeang},
        TITLE={A Genome-wide Short Hairpin RNA Screening of Jurkat T-cells for Human Proteins Contributing to Productive HIV-1 Replication},
       JOURNAL={J Biol Chem},
        YEAR={2009},
},

@article{ 8 ,
        AUTHOR={Brass ALand Dykxhoorn DM},
        TITLE={Identification of host proteins required for HIV infection through a functional genomic screen},
        JOURNAL={Pubmed},
        YEAR={2008},
},

 @article{ 9,
        AUTHOR={Christopher M. Sassetti and Eric J. Rubin},
        TITLE={Genetic requirements for mycobacterial survival during infection},
       JOURNAL={PNAS},
        YEAR={2003},
},

@article{ 10,
        AUTHOR={Nadav Rappoport and Michal Linial},
        TITLE={Viral Proteins Acquired from a Host Converge to Simplified Domain Architectures},
        JOURNAL={PLoS Computattional Biology},
        YEAR={2012},
},
```

Main document:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\title{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx: An Overview}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}


\bibliographystyle{acm}
\bibliography{refer}
\end{document}
```

bibstyle=acm 
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  There are several factors affecting this.  Please post a  [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Comment: I have tried and also

Comment: Can you show us a sample `.bib`entry that causes the problem? Ideally you would also add information about your BibTeX/`biblatex` styles and options.

Comment: Assuming a well-formed 'bib entry', the 'problem' you are experiencing is likely due to the bibliography style you have chosen (usually loaded with the command `\bibliographystyle`, though it may be hard-coded into the `cls` or possibly a `sty` file). We therefore need to see a minimal file as suggested.

Comment: Is there no dot after `W`?

Comment: i have used alpha here .....

Comment: umm.. this is my first latex, so i really dont know what ref is... what does one use instead of ref?

Comment: If you're using the `alpha` bibliography style,  why do you get a numeric label -- "[3]" -- next to the entry authored by de Jong et al?

Comment: okay i have changed it to acm..

Comment: @jon - Assuming a well-formed bib entry..." Is that an indirect way of hinting that the bib entry may not exactly be well-formed? :-)

Comment: @Mico -- ha, you caught me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Aside: This answer was updated fully after the OP posted a corrected set of bibliographic entries.)

Thanks for updating the set of bibliographic entries, so that they are now minimally compilable. A comment up front: The issue with some names being truncated to initials should be gone completely. I trust you can no longer generate "T. v. d. P".

You still need to apply a few more corrections. Among them are:

- First and foremost, be sure to list *all authors* of a publication. For entry #8, you currently list only two of the eight [8!] authors (and you manage to have three syntax errors in the truncated author field). Why suppress 75 percent of the author names? If you must truncate the list, write `and others` at the end of the author field. (By the way, the article was published in *Science*.)
- Be sure to get the uppercasing of middle initials right. If you write `Hanna k. de Jong`, BibTeX will treat "k." as belonging to the "von component" of the author's full name. Do write `Hanna K. de Jong`. This will ensure that the item is sorted under "D" (for "de Jong") rather than under "K" (for "k. de Jong").
- Since the `acm` bibliography style applies "sentence style" to the contents of the `title` field, it is essential to encase words that *must not be converted to lowercase* -- such as "HIV" and "RNA" -- in curly braces.
- Be careful not to use non-ASCII characters such as `–` ("en-dash") in the bib file. Instead, write `--` (two consecutive ordinary dashes).

Two final suggestions: First, please consider adding fields such as `volume`, `number`and `pages` to the entries of type `@article`; while it's not "compulsory" to provide these pieces of information, your readers will almost certainly appreciate you doing so. Second, do consider using keys that are a bit more mnemonic than "1", "2", etc. You'll find that issuing various `\cite` instructions will become much more manageable if you use mnemonic keys.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybibliography.bib}
@article{ 1,
        AUTHOR={Anu Raghunathan and Jennifer Reed},
        TITLE={Constraint-based analysis of metabolic capacity of {Salmonella} typhimurium during host-pathogen interaction},
        JOURNAL={BMC Systems Biology},
        YEAR={2009},
}

@article{ 2,
        AUTHOR={Hanna K. de Jong and Chris M. Parry and Tom van der Poll and W. Joost Wiersinga},
        TITLE={Host--Pathogen Interaction in Invasive Salmonellosis},
        JOURNAL={PLoS Pathogens},
        YEAR={2012},
 }

@article{ 3,
        AUTHOR={Vinod Scaria and Manoj Hariharan and Beena Pillai and Souvik Maiti and Samir K. Brahmachari},
        TITLE={Host--virus genome interactions: macro roles for {microRNAs}},
        JOURNAL={Cellular Microbiology},
        YEAR={2007},
 }

@article{ 4 ,
        AUTHOR={Zhumur Ghosh and Bibekanand Mallick and Jayprokas Chakrabarti},
        TITLE={Cellular versus viral {microRNAs} in host--virus interaction},
        JOURNAL={Nucleic Acids Research},
        YEAR={2009},
}

@article{ 5 ,
        AUTHOR={Vinod Scaria and Manoj Hariharan and Samir K. Brahmachari},
        TITLE={Host-virus interaction: a new role for {microRNAs}},
        JOURNAL={BioMedCentral},
        YEAR={2006},
 }

@article{ 6 ,
        AUTHOR={Renate Konig and Yingyao Zhou},
        TITLE={Global Analysis of Host-Pathogen Interactions that Regulate Early-Stage {HIV-1} Replication},
        JOURNAL={Cell},
        YEAR={2008},
}

@article{ 7,
        AUTHOR={Man Lung Yeung and Laurent Houzet and Venkat S.R.K. Yedavalli and Kuan-Teh Jeang},
        TITLE={A Genome-wide Short Hairpin {RNA} Screening of {Jurkat T-cells} for Human Proteins Contributing to Productive {HIV-1} Replication},
       JOURNAL={J Biol Chem},
        YEAR={2009},
},

@article{ 8 ,
        AUTHOR={Abraham L. Brass and Derek M. Dykxhoorn and Yair Benita 
        and Nan Yan and Alan Engelman and Ramnik J. Xavier and Judy
        Lieberman and Stephen J. Elledge},
        TITLE={Identification of host proteins required for {HIV} infection through a functional genomic screen},
        JOURNAL={Science},
        YEAR={2008},
}

@article{ 9,
        AUTHOR={Christopher M. Sassetti and Eric J. Rubin},
        TITLE={Genetic requirements for mycobacterial survival during infection},
        JOURNAL={PNAS},
        YEAR={2003},
},

@article{ 10,
        AUTHOR={Nadav Rappoport and Michal Linial},
        TITLE={Viral Proteins Acquired from a Host Converge to Simplified Domain Architectures},
        JOURNAL={PLoS Computational Biology},
        YEAR={2012},
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliographystyle{acm}
\hyphenation{micro-RNAs brahma-chari}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: is it compulsory to supply volume issue and pages?

Comment: Overfull \hbox (37.5505pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 8--14
\tenrm Wiersinga, TI-TLE=HostPathogen In-ter-ac-tion in In-va-sive Salmonel-los
is, JOUR-NAL=PLOS Pathogens, YEAR=2012,|

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 8--14


Overfull \hbox (25.02364pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 22--28
\tenrm TLE=Cellular ver-sus vi-ral mi-croR-NAs in hostvirus in-ter-ac-tion, JOU
R-NAL=Nucleic Acids Re-search, YEAR=2009,|

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 22--28

)

Comment: I got this error after making the change

Comment: @user3237995 - Please repost the entire corrected bib file. It is not possible to tell what's going on from the warning message you report getting.

Comment: @user3237995 You don't have to supply volume, pages or whatever, but depending on the reference it might be useful to do so.

Comment: @user3237995 That warning message you've posted suggests you are trying to typeset your `.bib` file.

Comment: can any of you provide me a sample correct bib file??

Comment: @Mico, I will create a separate .bib file right?

Comment: @user3237995 - By all means, create a separate bib file. The code in the answer above (which uses a `filecontents` environment to create a new file "on the fly") is intended to make the example self-contained. For a real document, it's better to create an entirely separate bib file. That way, one and the same bib file can be used by multiple tex files.

Comment: 2mico I am getting this error after I made the necessary changes:                        
 ! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
                  {article}
?

Comment: @user3237995 - In which file -- the tex file or the bib file -- is the offending instruction located?

Comment: IS THERE ANY BIBLIOGRAPHY STYLE WHICH WOULD DISPLAY NAMES EXACTLY AS i HAVE WRITTEN IN THE DOCUMENT INSTEAD OF SHORTENING IT?

Comment: @user3237995 - THAT'S A NEW QUESTION. PLEASE POST A NEW QUERY, IN WHICH YOU EXPLAIN THE EXACT FORMATTING REQUIREMENTS.

Comment: @Mico the bib file is offending me

Comment: @user3237995 - There should never be a `\documentclass` instruction in a bib file.

Comment: @Mico :P okay then why did you write that :P sorry for asking such stuppid questions, once I get the hang of it, I will bother less

Comment: @user3237995 - The code in my answer uses the `filecontents` package to create the file `mybibliography.bib` "on the fly". The file `mybibliography.bib` contains the material between `\begin{filecontents}{mybibliography.bib}` and `\end{filecontents}`: only bibliographic entries -- and no TeX or LaTeX macros. For your real project, you should create the bib file using a text editor.